# nHibernate QueryOver build programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, queryover

Hello is there an option to build queryover from nhibernate programmatically from code ?

I don't know how many restriction will be , how many tables i'm building automat that will make queryover from a list of objects.

Comment: QueryOver is just a type-safe, magic-string-less way of building Criteria queries, so yes... by using Criteria!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are specifically dealing with? This kind of thing is possible... to a point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are talking about dynamic restrictions then you could do:

```
var query = _session.QueryOver<Something>();
if(someterm!=null)
   query.Where(x=>x.SomeTerm==someTerm);

if(someotherterm!=null)
   query.Where(x=>x.SomeOtherTerm==someotherterm);

var results = query.List();
```

You could even join dynamically if you need to like:

```
if(something!=null){
  SomeReference srAlias = null;
  query.JoinAlias(x=>x.SomeReference,()=>srAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
       .Where(x=>srAlias.Something==something);
}
```